# Installing same application with different names

Tags: android, manifest

How can I install the sample application with different names on Android device ?

I have developed one application. I want to install two instances of the same application, one with real data and another one with dummy data.

How can I do this?

[solution]

I followed below steps for my dummy applicaiton:

project -> Android tools -> Rename Application package.

Now both instances are running fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Android Studio browse the project to Gradle Scripts>build.gradle(Module:app) and change **applicationId**.

Answer (score 1):

Just you need to change the package name of your application. And you will get the two instances of same application.

Comment: I have tried by changing packing name in manifest file. After that application getting crashed when I install

Comment: Change your package names, not only on the manifest but your classes as well.

Comment: Do as @Ndupza said. You also need to change the pacakge name of your application packages also not only in manifest. It will surely crash if you have only change the package name in manifest. As it will not be able to get files from the package.